# How to add an ellipsis in a Django template using truncatewords without the final space?

Tags: django, templates, truncate, trim

The truncatewords filter inserts a space before the elipsis. As in,
'A fine holiday recipe book of ...'
vs. the desired
'A fine holiday recipe book of...'

Is there an easy way to get this filter to not put a space there? I could take care of this in the view pretty easily, but would prefer to do it in the template - ideally without creating a custom filter. Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a bunch of template filters at [Djangosnippets](http://djangosnippets.org/tags/truncate/), and [this one looks pretty neat](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1259/):

```
# From http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1259/

from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def truncatesmart(value, limit=80):
    """
    Truncates a string after a given number of chars keeping whole words.

    Usage:
        {{ string|truncatesmart }}
        {{ string|truncatesmart:50 }}
    """

    try:
        limit = int(limit)
    # invalid literal for int()
    except ValueError:
        # Fail silently.
        return value

    # Make sure it's unicode
    value = unicode(value)

    # Return the string itself if length is smaller or equal to the limit
    if len(value) <= limit:
        return value

    # Cut the string
    value = value[:limit]

    # Break into words and remove the last
    words = value.split(' ')[:-1]

    # Join the words and return
    return ' '.join(words) + '...'
```

Comment: Yeah, I have something similar as a function for views. I reckon might as well just make a template tag out of it, hmm? Thanks for the link.

Comment: Hmm, the question remains why the default Django behaviour is to insert a space when this is incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

This will also work:

```
{{ value|truncatewords:3|slice:"-4" }}...
```

Basically, just slice off the last 4 characters (ellipse plus space), and then add it back without the space!

The neat thing is, with this method you can also end your, uh, truncation with anything you'd like.

Comment: The obvious problem with this method is that if your `value` is shorter than the number passed to `truncatewords`, then you're just cutting off the last 4 characters and adding an ellipse. Of course, you could always work around that by measuring the length of `value` and using an `if` loop.

Comment: In addition to the above-mentioned excessive truncation, this will also always add the `...`, even if the string is short enough (e.g `"blah"|truncatewords:3` would show `blah`, not `blah...`).

Comment: To put jbpjackson and dbr's comments in other words, please don't do this.